# What is the difference between the two sentences? (Have you been ... before? AND have you ever been...?)

Tags: meaning, nuance

1. Have you been to Japan before?
2. Have you ever been to Japan? 
   What is the difference between the two sentences? 
   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first question (*Have you been to Japan before?*) is most likely to be asked when you and your conversation partner are actually in Japan or are discussing a plan to visit it.

A similar question is (*Have you ridden a horse before?*). You are sitting on a horse or discussing a plan to ride one.

The second question (*Have you ever been to Japan?*) would be rather unlikely to be asked when you are actually in Japan. It is more likely to be an *out-of-the-blue* question similar to *Have you ever ridden a horse?* It is also possible when discussing a plan to visit Japan or to ride a horse.

Answer (score -2):

In the first sentence you are asking a person whether in their whole past they made **a stay or more** in Japan. You could say that more concisely as "Have you been to japan?" and if the context is right there is no ambiguity. In the context of a circle of people who travel a lot, this can mean what is expressed by the more usual "Have you been to Japan lately?".

In the second sentence you are asking whether in  the past the person  made **at any one time a stay** in japan.

The two sentences come down roughly to the same thing, which  is to ask someone whether in their past life they made **a stay** in Japan.